# Limit of sequence of nonnegative $\mu$-integrable functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove the following statements:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f_1, f_2, ... \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ be nonnegative and such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu$ exists. Assume $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere, where $f$ is measurable.

(i) Show that $f \in \mathcal{L}^1{(\mu)}$ and

(ii) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int |f_n - f|d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu - \int f d\mu$.

The first statement I managed to prove using Fatou's lemma. Namely, we have

$$
\int f d\mu = \int \lim_{n \to \infty}d\mu \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu < \infty,
$$
and so $f \in \mathcal{L}^1{(\mu)}$. For the second statement, we know by the linearity of the integral that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu - \int f d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int (f_n -  f) d\mu$. Here I think I can somehow invoke the idea that $f_n$ is close to $f$ for large $n$ except for a $\mu$-null set, but I am not sure how to continue with this. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks! For those who want to look it up, this is exercise 4.2.2 in Achim Klenke's Probability Theory.

Comment: Note that $f\in L^1$ iff $\int |f|d\mu <\infty$, you need the absolute value...

Comment: @Yanko If $f_n$ are nonnegative, then so is $f$ almost surely. Anyway, the statement goes through with the absolute value.

Comment: Ah sorry I did not see. Try to look up "Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem", you will get what you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second part is essentialy Scheffe's Lemma.
$\int (f-f_n)^{+} \to 0$ by DCT with dominating function $f$.

Let $L=\lim \int f_n$. Then $\int (f-f_n) \to \int f -L$. Now $\int (f-f_n)^{-} =\int (f-f_n)^{+} -\int (f-f_n) \to L-\int f$. So $\int |f-f_n| =\int (f-f_n)^{+}+\int (f-f_n)^{-} \to L-\int f$.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with your solution, but this exercise should be solvable without invoking DCT, since it comes way before it in the textbook. Could one instead use Fatou's lemma for $-(f-f_n)^{+}$? Then, one would have (I think) $0 \leq \lim \int (f - f_n)^{+} d\mu \leq 0$ and hence conclude the same thing?

Comment: In any case, you've solved my problem, so thanks!

Comment: @Nirai $-(f-f_n)^{+}$ is not non-negative so Fatou's Lemma doesn't apply. But you can apply Fatou's Lemma to $f-(f-f_n)^{+}$ to avoid DCT.

Comment: That's equivalent to the way I stated it with $-f$ being an integrable minorant of $-(f - f_n)^{+}$.